# How to get index of array element in cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I have array which a pushed to tableView, when i tap a row(cell) a need to get number of my array element in these row, how can a do these?

```
- (void)rightButtonClick:(MyTableView *)tableView row:(NSIndexPath*)row
{
    [delegate Show:(row.row+1)];
}
```

delegate

```
-(void)Show:(NSInteger)row
{
    if(row >= 0)
    {
        NSLog(@" %d ", row);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not showing the code you've written, that's just a placeholder for code you want someone here to write.

Comment: TableView or UITableView? What is up with the button? row = indexPath? Man, this code is bad!

Comment: @Eiko it's not all code) interface MyTableView : UIView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

Comment: You have a **UIView** that is a TableView delegate and controller? My God, man, MVC. MVC. Think of the Children. My eyes, my eyes! The Goggles, they do nothing!

Comment: @Abizern i don't need somebody write code for me, i need example, few rows, if i have well known of syntax i'll not write here.

Comment: @Abizern Good it's not my code! I'm appending after someone...

Comment: Then rewrite it; don't just stick a plaster over it and hope it works.

Comment: @Abizern i start developing two weeks ago, unfortunately i can't :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if I'm understanding your English incorrectly, but I guess this is along the lines of what you want:

You can get the indexPath of the row that was selected in a table by implementing `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in you tableView's delegate (presumably your tableViewController). An indexPath has two properties you'll be interested in; `section` and `row`. If you have one section in your table, and one 1d array of data, you can simply use something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyObject *object = [self.myListOfObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

If you have more than one section, you will need to use indexPath.section as well, depending on what your model looks like.

Comment: Sorry for my English :)
Now i'm using the same code as you write, i get index of row, number of row and it works correctly, but when i use search in my table i find one element, for example in array he had 53 number but after searching his row number changed to 1, because i find him, before searching he was 53, in row #53, i hope you understand me)

Comment: No problem :) ok, so what do you mean by 'when I use search in my table...'?

Comment: i have searchBar, put there name of my array element, so all elements are hiding and i see only one which i searched) so he changes his row number and i get wrong element number)

Comment: Ok, that's an entirely different question on how to use the searchBar with a table. You should ask another question for that, maybe with some code.

Comment: my search works fine, i just need to get number of array element, not number of row with element

Comment: @RomanSimenok As I mentioned before, can you please post the code where you want this index value.

Comment: @trojanfoe edited, i don't knew how cat it help you or me)